# Extjs form submitting multiple times

Tags: forms, extjs, submission

I'm using a form for edit some records. Each time When Edit link is clicked i'm loading one record data into form, changing the values and updating, its worked fine for the first time.

When i load another record data into form and update it, the present record is updating and the previous record is also updating with the new data.

If i update 3 rows after that when updated the 4th row, 4th row and previous 3 are updating with new data entered for 4th row.

I think form is submitting multiple times,
I used form reset property each time loading the values, but its not worked.

How to do this Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you holding your formpanel into a Ext.Window component ? Check if the window is actually closed or hidden. Try putting `closeAction: 'close'` in your window config.